# Reactjs _ Web animation APi - Animation to or from an underlying value is not yet supported

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation

I'm trying to create [this animation](https://mverissimo.github.io/tweenslideshow/) with ReactJS and Web animation API

I have opted for the WAAPI to explore mechanisms and I like it. The sole problem is that when trigger my web page Waapi returns me that

> animation to or from an underlying value is not yet supported.

I can't figure out what is wrong, maybe is the polyfill but I have imported the polyfill in my App.js file at top of my code.

Maybe is an other bug?

Here my [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ko798w4693)

Here my javascript logic, you can visualize the great steps of my component's logic via the good old constructor function :

```
  constructor( props ){
    super( props );

    // appreciate arrow or navigate move before trigger animation
    // update button view
    // stock nextIndex in state 
    this.animationPrepare = this.animationPrepare.bind(this);
    this.buttonBackground = this.buttonBackground.bind(this);
    this.updateNextView = this.updateNextView.bind(this);

    // set animation
    this.routeAnimationPosition = this.routeAnimationPosition.bind(this);
    this.setEnterAnimation = this.setEnterAnimation.bind(this);
    this.setExitAnimation = this.setExitAnimation.bind(this);

    // triger animation
    this.firstLineAnimation = this.firstLineAnimation.bind(this);
    this.secondLineAnimation = this.secondLineAnimation.bind(this);
    this.imageAnimation = this.imageAnimation.bind(this);

    // move pageView
    this.arrowMove = this.arrowMove.bind(this);
    this.circleMove = this.circleMove.bind(this);

    // trigger another loop __ update state data
    this.updateSlideData = this.updateSlideData.bind(this); 
  }

  componentDidMount(){ 
    this.animationPrepare();
      var body= document.body;
      body.style.overflow= "hidden";
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){ 
    var body= document.body;
    body.style.overflow= "scroll";    
  }


// slideState 
state={ 
  currentView:0,
  nextView:null,
  finalLoop:true,

  elementType:null,
  animation:this.enterDownAnimation,
  timing:this.slideAnimationTiming,  

  imageSource:"/static/assets/illustration/portfolio/chinese_cook.png",
  portfolioUrl:"",
  firstLineText:"first line",
  secondLineText:"secondLine"
}

// animation timing 
slideAnimationTiming={ 
  duration: 750,
  easing: "ease-in",
  delay: this.state.delay,
  iterations:1,
  direction: "normal",
  fill:  "forwards"
}

// animations forms
enterDownAnimation=[
  {transform:"translate(0, 30vh)", opacity:0},
  {transform:"translate(0, 30vh)", opacity:1},
  {offset:0.5, transform:"translate(0, 35vh)", opacity:1}
] 

enterUpAnimation=[
  {transform:"translate(0, 35vh)", opacity:0},
  {transform:"translate(0, 35vh)", opacity:1},
  {offset:0.5, transform:"translate(0, 30vh)", opacity:1}
] 

enterSideAnimation=[
  {transform:"translate(10vw)", opacity:0},
  {transform:"translate(10vw)", opacity:1},
  {offset:0.5, transform:"translate(030vh)", opacity:1}
] 

// exit animation

exitDownAnimation=[
  {transform:"translate(0, 30vh)", opacity:1},
  {transform:"translate(0, 0vh)", opacity:1},
  {offset:0.5, transform:"translate(0, 35vh)", opacity:0}
] 

exitUpAnimation=[
  {transform:"translate(0, 35vh)", opacity:1},
  {transform:"translate(0, 35vh)", opacity:1},
  {offset:0.5, transform:"translate(0, 30vh)", opacity:0}
] 

exitUpAnimation=[
  {transform:"translate(10vw)", opacity:1},
  {transform:"translate(10vw)", opacity:1},
  {offset:0.5, transform:"translate(030vh)", opacity:0}
] 

// define animations function
  // defineAnimation= () => { 
  //  {here code...}
  // }

// trigger logic depending on position's state

animationPrepare=(nextView, isArrow)=>{  
  console.log("in animation prepare");
  isArrow ? 
      this.setState({arrowMove: true})
      :
      this.setState({arrowMove: false})

  if(this.state.finalLoop === false){
    this.buttonBackground(nextView);
    this.updateNextView(nextView);
  }
  this.firstLineAnimation();
}

buttonBackground=(nextView)=>{  
  var buttonToTransparent=this.refs["button"+this.state.currentView];
  buttonToTransparent.style.backgroundColor="transparent";

  var buttonCurrentView=this.refs["button"+nextView]; 
  buttonCurrentView.style.backgroundColor="black";
}

updateNextView=(nextView)=>{ 
  this.setState({nextView})
}

routeAnimationPosition=()=>{ 
  if(this.state.finalLoop){ 
    this.setEnterAnimation();
  }else{ 
    this.setExitAnimation();
  }  
}

setEnterAnimation=()=>{ 
  if(this.state.elementType ==="text"){
    if(this.state.currentView % 2 === 0){ 
      this.setState({animation:this.enterDownAnimation});
    }else{
        this.setState({animation:this.enterUpAnimation}) 
    }    
  }else{ 
    switch(this.state.currentView){ 
      case 0: 
        this.setState({animation:this.enterSideAnimation});
        break;
      case 1: 
        this.setState({animation:this.enterUpAnimation});
        break;
      case 2: 
        this.setState({animation:this.enterDownAnimation});
        break;
      case 3: 
        this.setState({animation:this.enterSideAnimation});
        break;
      case 4: 
      this.setState({animation:this.enterUpAnimation});
        break;
      default:
        console.log("no animation found")
        break; // test return
    }
  }
}

setExitAnimation=()=>{ 
  if(this.state.elementType ==="text"){
    if(this.state.currentView % 2 === 0){ 
        this.setState({animation:this.exitDownAnimation});
    }else{
        this.setState({animation:this.exitUpAnimation}) 
    }
  }else{ 
    switch(this.state.currentView){ 
      case 0: 
        this.setState({animation:this.exitSideAnimation});
        break;
      case 1: 
        this.setState({animation:this.exitUpAnimation});
        break;
      case 2: 
        this.setState({animation:this.exitDownAnimation});
        break;
      case 3: 
        this.setState({animation:this.exitSideAnimation});
        break;
      case 4: 
      this.setState({animation:this.exitUpAnimation});
        break;
      default:
        console.log("no animation found")
        break; // test return
    }
  }
}


// animation triggering
// promise to set animation
// with promise resolved to trigger animation
firstLineAnimation=()=>{ 
  // stock next view in componentState
    /***** 
   *  SET PROMISE => 2 steps
   *    set animation position 
   *    set animation form
   * *****/

  // set animation
  this.setState({position:"text"}, 
    () => this.routeAnimationPosition()) 

    /***** 
   *  RESOLVE PROMISE => 3 steps _ inject animation in element
   *    set element
   *    define animation
   *    trigger animation
   * *****/ 
  var textFirstLine = this.refs.firstLineTextBox
  // promise start here
  var textFirstLineAnimation = textFirstLine.animate( 
    this.state.animation,
    this.state.timing
  );    
  // trigger animation 
  // promise end here
  textFirstLineAnimation.play()

  // call next animation
  var callSecondAnimation= this.secondLineAnimation(); 
  textFirstLineAnimation.onfinish = callSecondAnimation;
}

secondLineAnimation=()=>{ 
  // no delay because component listen 
  // for first animation finishing 
  // set animation
  var textSecondLine = this.refs.secondLineTextBox
  var textSecondLineAnimation = textSecondLine.animate( 
    this.state.animation,
    this.state.timing
  )

  // trigger animation 
  textSecondLineAnimation.play();

  // call next animation
  var callImageAnimation= this.imageAnimation(); 
  textSecondLineAnimation.onfinish = callImageAnimation;
}

imageAnimation=()=>{ 
  // no delay because component listen 
  // for second animation finishing 
  // set animation
  // promise start here
  this.setState({position:"image"}, 
    () => this.routeAnimationPosition())

  // inject animation in element
  var imageBox =  this.refs.imageBox
  // promise resolve in imageAnimation
  var imageAnimation = imageBox.animate( 
    this.state.animation,
    this.state.timing
  )

  // trigger animation 
  imageAnimation.play();

  // call updateSlideData function
  if(this.state.arrowMove && !(this.state.finalLoop)){ 
    var callArrowMove= () => this.arrowMove();
    imageAnimation.onfinish = callArrowMove;    
  }
  else if( !(this.state.arrowMove) && !(this.state.finalLoop)){ 
    var callCircleMove = () => this.circleMove();
    imageAnimation.onfinish = callCircleMove;    
  }
  else{ 
    var callUpdateSlideData = this.updateSlideData();
    imageAnimation.onfinish = callUpdateSlideData; 
  }
}

arrowMove=()=>{  
  // => move background to the relevant sliderView
  var imageHolder= this.refs.imageHolder;    
  var viewTravelValue=-(100*this.state.nextView);
  imageHolder.style.setProperty('--viewPosition', viewTravelValue+"vw");
  imageHolder.addEventListener("transitionend", function(event) {
    console.log("transition achieved")
    this.updateSlideData();   
  }, false);  

}

circleMove=()=>{ 
  // => move background to the relevant pageView
  var imageHolder= this.refs.imageHolder;    
  var viewTravelValue=-(100*this.state.nextView);
  imageHolder.style.setProperty('--viewPosition', viewTravelValue+"vw");  
  this.updateSlideData();  
  imageHolder.addEventListener("transitionend",()=> {
    console.log("transition achieved")
    this.updateSlideData();   
  }, false);   
} 



updateSlideData=()=>{  
  // console.log("STATE ACTION UPDATE DATA", this.state.action)
  // var indexUpdate=this.state.indexUpdate;

  if(this.state.finalLoop === false){ 
  var path = "/static/assets/illustration/portfolio/";
  var  imageSourceTab=[
    path + "chinese_cook.png",
    path+ "burger_cook.png",
    path +"french_cook.png",
    path +"chinese_cook.png",
    path+"burger_cook.png"
  ]
  var nextViewImage=imageSourceTab[this.state.nextView]

  // var firstLineTab=[ 
      /*****
       * 
       * code here
       * 
       *****/
  // ]
  // var secondLineTab=[ 
      /*****
       * 
       * code here
       * 
       *****/
  // ]
  // var nextViewFirstLine=firstLineTab[this.state.nextView]
  // var nextViewSecondLine=secondLineTab[this.state.nextView]  


  // var urlTab=[ 
      /*****
       * 
       * code here
       * 
       *****/
  // ]
  // var nextViewUrl=urlTab[this.state.nextView]


    // prepare nextView 
    // text => todo 
    this.setState({
      currentView:this.state.nextView,
      finalLoop:true, 
      imageSource:nextViewImage,
      // portfolioUrl:nextViewUrl,
      // firstLineText: nextViewFirstLine,
      // secondLineText:nextViewSecondLine
      },
      // inner_callback to ensure updated state 
      () => this.animationPrepare()
    )
  }else{ 
    // prepare the next pageView animation
    this.setState({
      finalLoop:false,
      isArrow:null
    })
    return
  }
}
```

My CSS stylesheet is about positioning the mains element, I think it's the logic which is very important here, especially since I use Waapi.

Any hint would be great,
thanks

Comment: If you must use React I'd recommend a lib like: https://github.com/chenglou/react-motion... `var body = document.body` is as React antipattern as you get.. If you want to use WAAPI - nothing wrong with plain vanilla JS...

Comment: thanks for answer, why it is antipattern please

Comment: In general, any lib that directly manipulates the DOM doesn't play nicely with React as React likes to be in charge of DOM manipulation... That's the short answer...

Comment: okay I see thanks for the hint, react-spring bypass react AFAIK, okay it is their job in an another side I can understand that if any